# Take picture and save it on internal storage

Tags: android, camera, internal-storage

I'm trying to take a picture and save it in the internal storage so this way, only my app will have access to the pictures
how can i do this? I'm trying a lot of things without success, even the official documentation from google is broken, here's my actual code, that saves on public directory:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pictures);

        imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        fabNewPicture = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fab_new_picture);
        fabNewPicture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                takePicture(v);
            }
        });

        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] { Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE }, 0);
        }
    }

    private void takePicture(View v)
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        file = Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile());
        i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, file);

        startActivityForResult(i, 100);
    }

    private static File getOutputMediaFile()
    {
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "FotoAula");

        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()){
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
                return null;
            }
        }

        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        return new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
                "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == 100) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                imageView.setImageURI(file);
            }
        }
    }
```

But this way the picture will become public and available even on the gallery, I don't want that, because I need to add some database info with each picture, so I need them to be private to my app...

How can i do this?

Thank you!

Comment: This is the answer that may suit you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22574350/how-to-keep-images-private-to-the-app-and-not-viewable-in-the-gallery

Comment: you can do two things.. 1st save your images with the period(.) prefix. This will hide your images from the gallery. 2nd- refer to this  https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal use openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE); and save your image.

Comment: The . preffix would be more like a workaround right? Or its really beign used in this kind of situation?

Comment: Can you help me to write the code of the 2nd situation?  Im struggling to understand the taking photo concept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you save your picture on SD card or external storage any app can access it. Try to get the private directory  and save your photo there.

Take from [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

To create and write a private file to the internal storage:

1-Call `openFileOutput()` with the name of the file and the operating mode. This returns a `FileOutputStream.`

2-Write to the file with `write()`.

3-Close the stream with `close()`.

For example:

```
String FILENAME = "hello_file";
String string = "hello world!";

FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
fos.write(string.getBytes());
fos.close();
```

Read "Using the Internal Storage" on: [Link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

Comment: Im trying to do this, but Im struggling to get it to work since I didnt understand the taking photo concept that much

Comment: Your application dont need take the picture itself, the picture is taked from camera app in your device in response to an intent send by your app. You need read the picture and copy to internal storage.

Please read this article:
https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html

Answer (score 2):

You cannot take a picture using camera intent and save to internal storage. It is just not allowed according to
[Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics)

> Generally, any photos that the user captures with the device camera should be 
>   saved on the device in the public external storage so they are accessible by all
>   apps.

However,

> However, if you'd like the photos to remain private to your app only, you can instead use the directory provided by getExternalFilesDir(). On Android 4.3 and lower, writing to this directory also requires the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission. Beginning with Android 4.4, the permission is no longer required because the directory is not accessible by other apps, so you can declare the permission should be requested only on the lower versions of Android by adding the maxSdkVersion attribute:

```
<manifest ...>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
                 android:maxSdkVersion="18" />
...
</manifest>
```

So you need to change `getOutputMediaFile()` method to this:

```
private static File getOutputMediaFile()
{
    File mediaStorageDir = context.getExternalFilesDir("FotoAula");

    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()){
        if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
            return null;
        }
    }

    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    return new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
            "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create a .nomedia file in your folder where you are saving your pictures and then media scanners in other apps will ignore your folder

Answer (score -2):

Private internal storage doesn't exist.When saving the picture,try to remove the suffix.Then it is not a picture for other application.

Comment: But I can save a picture this way? How can I show it latter without the suffix? By adding it only when I show? What about the storage that is removed when the user uninstalls the app? It is not the internal?

Comment: It is the bytes not the suffix that defines content of a file.A picture is always a picture even without suffix.You can surely show a picture without suffix in your app.

Comment: If you choose to save it on SDCard,then the pictures will still be there after uninstall.